# Take away frequent code

Tags: php, include

I have some code(dbName,dbPSWD etc) that must be used in many scripts. I moved it to  cfg.PHP file  and then include this code by `"*Require"*` command in appropriate place(at the beggining of script). 
Now i need to add to every script this line "`*mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';")`"*;  But this line must be added in middle of the scripts (not at beginning). For this reasons after including this line into cfg.PHP scripts works incorrectly.  I dont want to write this line in each script. May be i can to include this line into cfg.php, but with the condition that the line will  inserted at the middle of the script,  not at the place where REQUIRE command is use.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: I recommend you putting all the database stuff into a class and call that command (`SET NAMES 'utf-8';`) after successfully connecting to the database. Classes are in this case much better than functions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are your knight in shining armor. :)

cfg.php:

```
function set_names() {
  mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
}
```

pages:

```
set_names();
```

Comment: nonono, its not good idea. Now i need to add set_names(); function in every sript. With the same success i can write only  mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';"); in each script.I want modify only cfg.php file, without modifyng other scripts

Comment: @Isk You sant to run SET NAMES immediately after opening the connection.

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap the code inside the required file in a function, require it at the beggining of your main php file, and call the function in the required file before the `mysql_query` line

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) and change your code structure to work with it because it "requires" the file at the beginning of every file.